# Android query for contact content provider in two android platform(1.6) and android platform(2.2)

Tags: android

I am looking for the solution to get contact details (Phone,Email) from the device. I have implemented code for OS 1.6 as well as for 2.2. I am building an application with API level 4 (1.6), but when I run the build in 2.2 device I am getting email and phone string null.
                    do you have a proper solution for this? please replay...

Comment: It would be useful to see the code that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to get the calendar base uri, Since it has been changed from Os Version 2.2.

private String getCalendarUriBase() {

```
String calendarUriBase = null;
Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars");
Cursor managedCursor = null;
try {
    managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // eat
}

if (managedCursor != null) {
    calendarUriBase = "content://calendar/";
} else {
    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
    try {
        managedCursor = managedQuery(calendars, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // eat
    }

    if (managedCursor != null) {
        calendarUriBase = "content://com.android.calendar/";
    }

}

return calendarUriBase;
```

}